# Can't build unified api app with armv7s architecture

Tags: xamarin, 64-bit, sdwebimage

I built a Xamarin Unified API app.
When I build it using Armv7 + Arm64 architecture everything is ok.
But when I try to build it in the armv7s architecture I get errors related to a third party component - SDWebImage. The SDWebImage is added as a Component and not as a binding project (so I can't just add the [Protocol] attribute). The next error is 1 of 8 errors I get. Each for different class of the component. Anyone?

Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImagePrefetcher. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImagePrefetcher' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

Comment: Here's the source repo for this component.  I recommend opening an issue there, I doubt this is something that can be solved here. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the the SDWebImage Component does not include Armv7s code, only Armv7 and Arm64.

If you depend on SDWebImage and need Armv7s code, then you'll need to contact the vendor to publish an updated Component.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, But I'm facing another issue. Choosing armv7 + arm64 is fine, but when I choose only armv7 I get errors. this is one of them:             Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription' is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5211)

Comment: Please add "-v -v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options and pastebin a good and a bad build log.